# AH01425: I18n support in mod_proxy_html requires mod_xml2enc. Without it, non-ASCII characte

Tags: apache2, configuration

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed apache, postgres and deployed an ssl, but I am getting this error:

```
AH01425: I18n support in mod_proxy_html requires mod_xml2enc. Without it, non-ASCII characte
Jul 10 17:31:41 server.com apache2[2021]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 47 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-webui.conf:
Jul 10 17:31:41 server.com apache2[2021]: Can't load driver file apr_dbd_pgsql.so
Jul 10 17:31:41 server.com apache2[2021]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jul 10 17:31:41 server.com apache2[2021]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 10 17:31:41 server.com systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 10 17:31:41 server.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

Any solution?

Comment: Finally got the solution it was to run `a2enmod xml2enc`
Source  [https://dausruddin.com/i18n-support-in-mod_proxy_html-requires-mod_xml2enc-without-it-non-ascii-characters-in-proxied-pages-are-likely-to-display-incorrectly/]